# make an alias to move files to a tmp directory

Tags: alias, mv

I am trying to create an alias to move files and directories to the `tmp` directory.  This is what I've tried:

```
alias rm='/bin/mv *.* /tmp'
```

The problem is that when I type `rm filename`, I get an error saying:

```
/bin/mv: target 'filename' is not a directory.
```

I know that filename is just a file.  The point is that I want to move it to the specified `/tmp` directory.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: As Flimzy noted, it is impossible to do it with `alias`. However, even if it were possible, it would be a bad idea to use `alias`. First, if you are used to custom behavior of `rm` , you might be forced to use normal edition on some other machine (false sense of security). Second, if some other user is using your computer, and tries to erase some big 10GB binary file to save space, he would really expect that the file is deleted, and not just moved to the /tmp.

Comment: @bbaja42 has a valid point. **Never** go ahead and change the functionality of an essential built in command.

Answer (score 2):

Your alias means that when you type 'rm filename' you are really running this command:

```
/bin/mv *.* /tmp filename
```

That's obviously not what you want.  I don't think you can use an alias for this, because I don't think there's a way to re-order the arguments passed to an alias.  You'll be better off writing a short shell script that looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
mv "$@" /tmp
```

Note: You don't want *.* either, that looks like a Windowsism... that will only match filenames with periods in them. Many file names in Linux don't contain periods.

Comment: This will fail as soon as spaces are involved. `"$@"` is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
alias rm='mv -t /tmp '
```

using GNU Collection `mv` 8.13 on Ubuntu 12.04. Note the space after `/tmp`.